# Sums of logarithms $\small \log(1+1/1) + \log(1+1/2) + \ldots \log(1+1/n) $ how is this telescoping?

Tags: sequences-and-series

This is surely a tiny question but I seem to have some blackout currently ...
I tried to define a function for the sum of logarithms, like we have it for the sums of like powers with the bernoulli-polynomials. (I had a [question with sums of logarithms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39378/series-of-logarithms-sum-k-1-infty-lnk-ramanujan-summation) here on MSE earlier, but it is not directly translatable). I've got for the following sum of logarithms

$ \qquad \small \sum_{k=a+1}^b \log(1+1/k)) $

the equivalent expression:

$ \qquad \small  (\log(1/a)-\log(1+1/a) - ( \log(1/b)-\log(1+1/b)) $

but don't see, why.... This must have to do something with telescoping, but I just don't get it...

(The functions for the sums of the higher powers of the logarithms require series involving zetas as expected, so this simple contraction of a formula was extremely surprising)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\log(1 + 1/k) = \log(\frac{k + 1}{k}) = \log(k + 1) - \log(k)$

Comment: Oh I forgot... "**HINT**"!

Comment: arrggh... sometimes things are so simple... So my function was configured correctly; thanks!

Comment: Glad to help  :)

Comment: This is used in deriving an infinite series for the [Euler-Mascheroni](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Series_expansions) constant.

Comment: @anon: this page has become impressive, meanwhile. Thanks for the reminder...

Answer (score 6):

Write
$$
\sum_{k=a+1}^b\log(1+1/k)=\log\left(\prod_{k=a+1}^b\frac{k+1}{k}\right)
$$
or
$$
\sum_{k=a+1}^b\log(1+1/k)=\sum_{k=a+1}^b\log(k+1)-\log(k)
$$
Then you can work with a telescoping product or sum.