# Has the $\Gamma$-like function $f_p(n) = 1^{\ln(1)^p} \cdot 2^{\ln(2)^p} \cdot \ldots \cdot n^{\ln(n)^p} $ been discussed anywhere?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, special-functions, gamma-function

In an older fiddling with the gamma-function (expanding on the idea of sums of consecutive like-powers of logarithms, similarly as the bernoulli-polynomials for the sums of like powers of consecutive integers) I hadn't looked at the assumed approximations for the family of *p*-parametrized gamma-relatives (where p is nonnegative integer)
$$ \begin{align} f_p(n) & =\exp \left(\sum_{k=0}^n \ln(1+k)^p \right) \\ & = 1^{\ln(1)^{p-1}}\cdot 2^{\ln(2)^{p-1}} \cdots n^{\ln(n)^{p-1}} \end{align}$$ 
where $p \gt 1$       .

I just looked at that treatize and would like to improve it with some knowlegde about the functions $f_p$ where $p \gt 1$ (for $p=1$ this is the factorial function).

Q: Has someone seen one of these functions being discussed elsewhere?

---

Here is some context: 
[an older question at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87113) , [an older question at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39378), the original text discussing this idea initially [posted at the tetrationforum](http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/attachment.php?aid=915) a very q&d or, a bit better written in ["uncompleting the gamma"](http://go.helms-net.de/math/musings/UncompletingGamma.pdf), from page 13

Comment: I haven't seen anything explicit about it before, but certainly it seems like the standard derivation of Stirling via the Euler-MacLaurin formula along with knowledge of the incomplete gamma function would give asymptotics.  Is there something particular you're trying to find out?

Comment: @Steven: I don't expect too much, it is just to do some completion of the discussion in my 3'rd link, which I just provided in my question. Well - perhaps there is something "nice" in it anyway...